# Greengrass Error when start Daemon "No hardlink/softlink protection enabled" in Android 7 Nougat Shell

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, symlink, hardlink, aws-iot-greengrass

Can't start greengrass daemon core

Setting up greengrass daemon
Validating hardlink/softlink protection
AWS Greengrass detected insecure OS configuration: No hardlink/softlink protection enabled.

Comment: One way that I found  out, is to use amplify library. I don't know if it's include all the features in the core. https://docs.amplify.aws/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I found out, is to use amplify library. I don't know if it's include all the features in the core

docs.amplify.aws